# Criar uma lista a partir de um dicionário

Tags: python, loop, for, condição

tenho o seguinte dicionário

```
pessoas = [ 
   {'nome': 'Alex', 'idade': 45, 'cidade': 'São Paulo'},
   {'nome': 'Ana', 'idade': 23, 'cidade': 'Rio de Janeiro'},
   {'nome': 'Diego', 'idade': 25, 'cidade': 'Recife'}
   {'nome': 'Carol', 'idade': 41, 'cidade': 'Curitiba'}]
```

Como eu faço para criar uma lista com as cidades das pessoas com mais de 40 anos?

Eu fiz o seguinte código que imprimiu as cidades corretamente, mas não sei como transformar em uma lista por meio do laço de repetição:

```
cidades= []

for dados in pessoas:
    if dados['idade']>40:
        print(dados['cidade'])
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basicamente você só tem que criar uma lista e adicionar o nome da cidade das pessoas com mais de 40 anos, um exemplo seria:

```
cidades = list()

for dados in pessoas:
    if dados['idade'] > 40:
        # A função .append() adiciona o valor entre parênteses a lista
        cidades.append(dados['cidade'])

print(cidades)
```

Ao executar o código teremos o nome da cidade de Alex e Carol, pois são os únicos com mais de 40 anos no dicionário.
Output:

```
['São Paulo', 'Curitiba']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
cidades = [p["cidade"] for p in pessoas if p["idade"] > 40]
```